# Is it possible to set up a decentralized minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I haven't looked into it deeply yet, but I am wondering if it is possible to dedicate several computational power of different computer/servers for one instance of Minecraft. There are limitation of CPU core counts and RAM size on a single machine. How do popular Minecraft server network service provider such as [Hypixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypixel) solve this issue? Any insights?

Comment: hypixel isnt a server, its a server network. meaning its hundreds of individual servers combined

Comment: I'm fairly certain Minecraft really will only use one core, right? I might be compleely wrong

Comment: @Penguin Almost. In singleplayer, the client and the server are two completely separate tasks. Also some minor tasks like light updates are deferred to other threads that can run on other cores. But greatest bulk of work of the server is done in one thread on one core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypixel uses a software similar to [BungeeCord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/), which allows multiple servers to run under one name and sharing some files, and for you to be transferred between the servers. This is used as the hub system in almost all servers today. However, if you have one world, you cannot shard the server.

Comment: Thank you! This would be a great start for me to look in to.